# How to make an entire data table row an angular material button

Tags: css, button, angular-material, tablerow

How would one make an entire data table row, and material button?
[image: button on a single cell]

Here you see a button in a single cell in the material data table. But I want it so that if you hover the entire *row*, it gives the row the `mat-button` style.

Should I just be using css to achieve this with `:hover`? And could I cheat it somehow and use the same styling that angular-material is using?

Answer (score 0):

How about using buttons in each td and matching the colors for the other cells?

relevant **HTML**:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>No. </th>
    <th>Name </th>
      <th>Weight </th>
        <th>symbolDate </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor='let item of dataSource'>
      <td><button mat-button> {{item.position}}</button></td>
      <td><button mat-button> {{item.name}}</button></td>
      <td><button mat-button> {{item.weight}}</button></td>
      <td><button mat-button> {{item.symbolDate}}</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

relevant **CSS**:

```
tr td button{ width:100%;  }
tr:hover td  { background: rgba(110,110,110,1); }
```

[working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urlzb4)